# Xamarin Forms: How to place one layout on top of another layout

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-relativelayout

**I am trying to create a UI like below:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="33.4*" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#F0BB1D" Margin="-10">
                <Label Text="Daily Readings" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
             </StackLayout>

              <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#FD728B" Margin="-10">
                  <Label Text="Saint of the Day" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
               </StackLayout>

               <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#1FB5D6" Margin="-10">
                  <Label Text="Quiz of the Day" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
         </StackLayout>

         <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
             <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Image Source="ic_daily_reading_icon_xx.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="0" />
                  <Image Source="ic_saint_icon_xx.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="1" />
                   <Image Source="ic_quiz_icon_xx.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="2"/>
                 </Grid>
           </StackLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**How can I create a layout like the top? What property of relative layout needs to use to achieve this?**

Comment: You Absolute or Relative layout and you should be good

Comment: @FreakyAli I have put the entire layout inside of a Relativelayout, but what property of relativelayout need to use to achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's pretty simple, use the `TranslationY` property on your images view:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" 
       TranslationY="-20"
       Source="ic_daily_reading_icon_xx.png" 
       WidthRequest="30" 
       HeightRequest="30" />
```

Comment: Is this work good in tab devices? Currently, I don't have Mac access to test. Working as expected in mobile devices.

Comment: Can you please go through the last comment of the following thread? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/168617/xamarin-forms-how-to-place-an-icon-on-top-of-the-stacklayout#latest

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Roubachof.  Or you can put the stacklayouts in the same grid cell .

```
<Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Grid HeightRequest="30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#F0BB1D" >
                    <Label Text="Daily Readings" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#FD728B" >
                    <Label Text="Saint of the Day" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#1FB5D6" >
                    <Label Text="Quiz of the Day" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
            <Grid HeightRequest="30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Image BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image BackgroundColor="Red" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you please go through the last comment of the following thread?
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/168617/xamarin-forms-how-to-place-an-icon-on-top-of-the-stacklayout#latest

Comment: You can create a new thread and provide more details(sample) .And I will check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237400/xamarin-forms-gesturerecognizers-not-responding-well-to-tap-need-multiple-taps

Comment: Check my answer .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Button HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    <Button HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

Pay attention to `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` properties, these specify how controls are placed. (In my case the objects are anchored to top left corner)

And controls order matter. You can see that green button is on top of the red one, it's because in the code it's placed after the red one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the solution by Alex Logvin, I was able to superimpose images and text with transparency over a photo in my gammaDog application:

```
  <Grid>
    <ffimageloading:CachedImage
        x:Name="MyImage"
        Source="{Binding MyImage}" >
    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

    <Image HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           Rotation="{Binding Heading}"
           Source="arrow.png"
           Margin="75"
           x:Name="ImageArrow"/>
    <Image HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           Rotation="{Binding HeadingCompass}"
           Source="compass.png"/>
    <Label Text="{Binding MyTitle, StringFormat='{0}'}"
           FontSize="Large" TextColor="Red"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
    <Label Text="{Binding MyNote, StringFormat='{0}'}"
           FontSize="Large" TextColor="Red"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           VerticalTextAlignment="Bottom"></Label>
  </Grid>
```

[image: The top 3rd of this screen is the result of this xaml.]